# Enable 'send email to this conversation' for all users in slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

Manually I can enable 'send email to this conversation' functionality in Slack.

I'm wondering if there is a configuration to enable it globally for everyone or if there is an API to do it.

Didn't find any relevant API in https://api.slack.com/methods

This is the functionality I'm referring to: https://slack.com/intl/en-au/help/articles/206819278-Send-emails-to-Slack#h_01F4WDZG8RTCTNAMR4KJ7D419V

[image]

Comment: Why not ask their support for help? This does not look related to programming to me

Comment: I'm not a customer. At the moment only using their free trial version

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't an API method that controls the permissions around creating a channel e-mail, if you are on a paid plan you can set this for your workspace.  There's more information on the [Help Center page](https://slack.com/help/articles/360053335433-Manage-incoming-emails-for-your-workspace-or-organization)